# Failed to setup Cloud Foundry on vagrant with Bosh-lite

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to setup cloud foundry on my local machine, when I try to install [bosh-lite](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite) I got the following error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite
$ cd bosh-lite
$ vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: box_version
* The box 'cloudfoundry/bosh-lite' could not be found.
```

I tried to comment the `override.vm.box_version` inthe Vagrant file but then just the first error disappear, it still can't find the 'cloudfoundry/bosh-lite' box!

Here is my machine setup information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-server 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.4.3
$ VBoxManage -v
4.3.10_Ubuntur93012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to upgrade Vagrant on your machine. The [box_version feature](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/versioning.html) was introduced in 1.5. Bosh Lite is known to work with Vagrant 1.6.3 (as it is stated in the [Bosh Lite Readme](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite#prepare-the-environment)).

Comment: where I can find this version and how to install it?? when i check vagrant [download page](http://downloads.vagrantup.com/) the latest i can find is 1.3.5 !!

Comment: Looks like that is an old downloads area, use [this link](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).